# How to overide BackPressed of in the View Model of a Basic Page in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I am developing an application with MvvmLight.

I need to handle the HardwareButtons.BackPressed event in the ViewModel of a page. I need to decide, based on the ViewModel data, whether to go back or not (i.e. set e.Handled = true;)

It is clear to me how to do it in the View. Not clear to me how to do it in the MvvmLight ViewModel.

Something similar to this code taken from the View code:

```
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;

    private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed( object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e )
        {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog( "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Warning" );
        dlg.Commands.Add( new UICommand( "Yes", new UICommandInvokedHandler( CommandHandler1 ) ) );
        dlg.Commands.Add( new UICommand( "No", new UICommandInvokedHandler( CommandHandler1 ) ) );
        await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }

    private void CommandHandler1( IUICommand command )
        {
        var label = command.Label;
        switch ( label )
            {
            case "Yes":
                    {
                    this.Frame.Navigate( typeof( MainPage ) );
                    break;
                    }
            case "No":
                    {
                    break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: And why you can't do the same in viewModel? It is in a different project or what?

Comment: Yes. Different project.